# Eclipse project structure ANT and MAVEN

Tags: eclipse, ant, maven

I am trying to set up a project, but feel completely overwhelmed with lack of knowledge. In university we used netbeans which resolved project structure gently for us. As community leans towards eclipse I am trying to migrate there, but feel myself like a penguin not able to fly. I can't understand project structure where and what has to be added, do I have to define ANT or MAVEN manually in eclipse can they be integrated? Where to go ? Apache manuals are so complicated, why is that I can program in Java , but don't know the fundamentals, soo depressed, please anyone guide me. I find pieces on web, but seems can't build full picture in my head.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.  Basically, eclipse uses a workspace, which contains one .metadata directory used by the plugins and all of the project folders.  Projects can then be things like java projects, PDE projects, PHP projects, etc.

There is maven integration in eclipse which I would use, http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/  It was part of Indigo, which released June 2011.

Set up your java projects in your workspace, and then use m2e to mavenize them, or use m2e to generate the java projects into your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

[maven](http://maven.apache.org) provides a facility to [create a new project](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) with the required structure based on the type of project (jar, war, etc.).

You can do this or achieve it directly from Eclipse as suggested by Paul Webster, by installing the m2e plugin.

This structure can then be easily built using maven, as well as developed in Eclipse.